# forensically deleting/updating data

Tags: oracle, security

I have a need to forensically remove data from oracle. If I just delete it, my understanding is the data will still actually be in the data file until that space is reused. I'm not concerned about the redo/archive/undo space, those will age out reasonable quickly.

Is there any methods for ensuring data is actually removed from a data file?

Answer (score 15):

This is an interesting question: When does Oracle really delete data physically ?

The unit of data in Oracle is a block. Let's see what happens when we delete a row.

Here's an example with a simple table on 11gR2 (see "[How to dump Oracle Data Block?](http://blogs.oracle.com/sysdba/entry/how_to_dump_oracle_data_block)"):

```
CREATE TABLE test_delete_data(id NUMBER,data VARCHAR2(100));
INSERT INTO test_delete_data VALUES (1, rpad('1', 100, '1'));
INSERT INTO test_delete_data VALUES (2, rpad('2', 100, '2'));
INSERT INTO test_delete_data VALUES (3, rpad('3', 100, '3'));
COMMIT;

SELECT dbms_rowid.rowid_to_absolute_fno(rowid, user, 'TEST_DELETE_DATA') fileno,
       dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(rowid) blockno
  FROM test_delete_data;

-- replace with values from query
alter system dump datafile 4 block 16573;
```

You should get something like this at the end of the file created in your `user_dump_dest` directory:

```
data_block_dump,data header at 0x8b02264
===============
[...]
block_row_dump:
tab 0, row 0, @0x1f2d
tl: 107 fb: --H-FL-- lb: 0x1  cc: 2
col  0: [ 2]  c1 02
col  1: [100]
 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31
 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31
 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31
 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31
tab 0, row 1, @0x1ec2
tl: 107 fb: --H-FL-- lb: 0x1  cc: 2
col  0: [ 2]  c1 03
col  1: [100]
 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32
 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32
 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32
 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32
tab 0, row 2, @0x1e57
tl: 107 fb: --H-FL-- lb: 0x1  cc: 2
col  0: [ 2]  c1 04
col  1: [100]
 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33
 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33
 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33
 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33
end_of_block_dump
```

If I delete the second row, commit and dump the same block, I will get something like this:

```
block_row_dump:
tab 0, row 0, @0x1f2d
tl: 107 fb: --H-FL-- lb: 0x0  cc: 2
col  0: [ 2]  c1 02
col  1: [100]
 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31
 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31
 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31
 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31
tab 0, row 1, @0x1ec2
tl: 2 fb: --HDFL-- lb: 0x2 
tab 0, row 2, @0x1e57
tl: 107 fb: --H-FL-- lb: 0x0  cc: 2
col  0: [ 2]  c1 04
col  1: [100]
 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33
 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33
 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33
 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33
end_of_block_dump
```

The record is still there (with a `D` flag set). If we look at the actual binary data (just before the `block header dump` section, we see that the data has not yet been overwritten:

```
8B040C0 33336404 33333333 33333333 33333333  [.d33333333333333]
8B040D0 33333333 33333333 33333333 33333333  [3333333333333333]
        Repeat 4 times
8B04120 33333333 023C3333 03C10202 32323264  [333333<.....d222]
8B04130 32323232 32323232 32323232 32323232  [2222222222222222]
        Repeat 5 times
8B04190 02002C32 6402C102 31313131 31313131  [2,.....d11111111]
8B041A0 31313131 31313131 31313131 31313131  [1111111111111111]
        Repeat 4 times
8B041F0 31313131 31313131 31313131 30A30602  [111111111111...0]
```

One way to force data to actually be overwritten would be to update it to a meaningless value before deleting the row. This wouldn't work with indexes since updates are translated to delete+insert in a b*tree index.

Comment: +1 "One way to force data to actually be overwritten would be to update it to a meaningless value before deleting the row."

Comment: Great answer! I'd like to add that you can implement the the "update before delete" with a _instead of trigger_.

Comment: If you want to make sure that index data is also overwritten you can shrink the table, rebuild all indexes (of that table), create a new table with PCT_FREE=99 which you extend until it consumes all free space and then fill this table with dummy rows. Finally you can drop the table to free space. This is definitely not a task you should do automatically after each delete. Also keep in mind to disable autoextend before performing this operation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think data persists after a delete but you're correct that the space will be kept in use by that table until it has been refilled. The top space usage in a table is known as the high water mark. Tom Kyte has a really good (unsurprisingly) [post](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:492636200346818072) about it.

You reduce the high water mark by rebuilding the table:

```
alter table my_table_name move
```

or by truncating it; though in an active table this is obviously not an option.

Comment: ISTBC, but I would expect the data still to exist (in "raw" form) after a delete.  It'll be there, it's just that the row has been "unlinked" from the table and the space marked as free.  Tom Kyte says this "So, when you delete the information, the block is still "a block", it is just a block that once had active rows - but no longer does."  I'm not 100% sure of this though, so no downvote.  :)

Comment: @cagcowboy, he also says "we might have many blocks that **no longer contain data**". I have always taken this to mean that the space is kept for future use but the data is gone. I'm willing to be proved incorrect though :-).

Comment: I see your point.  However, I would surmise that he could have written "we might have many blocks that no longer contain **active** data."  Basically, I wouldn't expect Oracle to *overwrite* deleted data - I think it just unreferences it.