# How to permanently delete a row in oracle forever

Tags: oracle

I want to delete a record from a table and no one should ever be able to recover the deleted data.
I have done delete operation but the record is still in the undo segments. And one can do flashback and retrive that row.

Comment: yes, but it does not tell anything about the record in undo and redo segments

Comment: Define "ever". Are we allowed to recover deleted data by restoring from a year-old offsite backup tape?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to hide something?

Answer (score 9):

There is likely a more streamlined set of steps, but here is a start.

- Delete the data out of any materialized views or home grown
  replication methods using triggers or the like.
- Delete the data out of any database audit tables.
- Change the database to noarchivelog.
- Create a new undo tablespace.
- Switch log files until all are archived.
- Shutdown the database.
- Turn off and purge any storage or virtual machine level snapshot capability.
- Delete all trace files that may contain the data.
- Delete all backups sets including archive log backups that could contain the data.
- Delete all OS audit logs that could contain the data.
- Visit any computer that may have the data cached or displayed and destroy it there.
- Visit any other storage devices the data may have been copied to and purge those.
- Find any hard copies of the data and destroy those.
- If someone memorized the data, memory erasure is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Is this serious? I think the OP just wants to get rid of the bytes within the database files and logs. Related: [forensically deleting/updating data](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12958/forensically-deleting-updating-data) But of course I'm being presumptious

Comment: I would also recommend to move the table to a new tablespace on a new disk drive and procedurally rewrite all the old disks. Else forensic analysis could probably retrieve the old data. Moving a table will only copy logically existing data.

Comment: @Vincent Malgrat - Indeed, and do the same procedural rewrite for all storage media that were storing backups, trace files, etc.

Comment: It's incredible how Oracle gets in the way at every step to protect data =)

Comment: my boss is a weirdo. He doesnot know what he wants. I recommended him to move to a new tablespace, but it is not practical to do each and everytime. So i told him to use Virtual Private Database. Thanks all for your time and answers